# Сервис или программа для генерации изображений для разных экранов

Tags: android-sdk, android

Здравствуйте , подскажите может есть возможность автоматически создавать из изображения другие изображения для различных экранов, подобно тому как делает сама IDE при создании кастомной иконки . То есть чтобы вручную не делать отдельно ресурсы для разных экранов( drawable-xxx). 
Буду благодарен.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Конечно! Сервисов много, но мне больше всего понравился [`Android Asset Studio`](http://android-ui-utils.googlecode.com/hg/asset-studio/dist/index.html). Этот сервис поможет вам сэкономить кучу времени и нервов =)

Comment: Спасибо большое , видел этот сервис. А вот мне в моем случае нужны изображения для экрана загрузки(то есть на весь экран)splash screen. Подскажите как в этом случае поступить ?

Answer (score 3):

пользуюсь script-fu "save android" для GIMP - при всей своей кривости - он лучше чем Android Asset Studio хотя бы тем, что не оквадрачивает изображения.

Comment: Поподробнее можно что это за зверь?

Comment: http://izvornikod.com/Blog/tabid/82/EntryId/5/GIMP-script-for-creating-Android-icons-at-once.aspx